# Buying ASUS ROG Strix 1000W 80 PLUS Gold Power Supply

Tags: power-supply

I am currently in Egypt and Egypt operates on a 220V supply voltage and 50Hz. I am planning to buy ASUS ROG Strix 1000W 80 PLUS Gold Power Supply from the US using Amazon and its specifications are found [here](https://rog.asus.com/us/power-supply-units/rog-strix/rog-strix-1000g-model/). I just need to make sure that this power supply will work safely in Egypt. Its input voltage is 100-240V ac, and hence, it can safely work with an input voltage of 220V. However, I can't find its input frequency specs. So is it safe to buy it?

Comment: It will almost certainly work fine, but you could ask Asus support just to be sure.

Comment: If you can't get one directly in Egypt, why not buy one in Europe instead? Then you'd be certain it can take 240v/50Hz. Shipping is likely to be cheaper too.